# What is the point of using archive.php instead of index.php?

Tags: theme-development, templates, template-hierarchy

**Dumb Questions Ahead:**

- If `index.php` and `archive.php` are practically the same thing, what's the point of having `archive.php`?
- When should I ever want to use `archive.php` over `index.php`?
- If I use front-page and Blog, it doesn't switch to `archive.php` which you might expect to and then use `index.php` in the place of `front-page.php`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`index.php` and `archive.php` might be the same but don't *have to be* the same. `index.php` will display your blog post archive and in the absence of `archive.php` (or other more specific archive files) it will display your date, author, etc. archives as well. But it doesn't have to.

You can, if you want, display your archived differently that your main blog index. That is the point of those specialized files-- they allow you to alter the look of specific pages without having to write complicated conditionals into the `index.php` file.

The difference between the two files is what you make of it. That difference can be a lot or none.

## Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy